# jQuery or Javascript how to find if a checkbox is checked in a rails form and delete the form div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

So I have and html page with a bunch of form elements like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/lists/17" class="edit_list" data-remote="true" id="edit_list_17" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch"></div><input name="list[complete]" type="hidden" value="0"><input id="list_complete" name="list[complete]" type="checkbox" value="0">

  <a class="btn btn-default btn-danger btn-xs" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" href="/lists/17" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a><label for="list_complete">1</label>
  <a class="btn btn-default btn-info btn-xs" href="/lists/17">Show</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default btn-warning btn-xs" href="/lists/17/edit">Edit</a>

</form>
```

what I need to do is grab that **type="checkbox" value="0"** and check if the value is 1, and if it is 1 remove the entire div. Is there any easy way to do that?

currently I can get the value of the first form element but have been trying for hours and no way to filter down or anything

This will find all the forms:

```
$('div#incomplete').children().find('form')
```

This will find the value of the first checkbox:

```
$('div#incomplete').children().find('form').find('input:checkbox:first').attr('value')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and [:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
var checked = $('div#incomplete').children().find('form').find('input:checkbox:first').is(':checked')
```

---

If you want to find all the checked checkboxes then

```
var $checks = $('#incomplete').find('form input:checkbox:checked')
```

---

If you want to remove the form

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#incomplete form').has('input:checkbox:checked').remove()
})
```

Comment: That will find me the first one but I need to find all of them

Comment: @JoelSmith you want find all the checked checboxes?

Comment: @JoelSmith can you explain `what I need to do is grab that type="checkbox" value="0" and check if the value is 1, and if it is 1 remove the entire div. Is there any easy way to do that?` again

Comment: There may be a better way to see if the element is checked or not... but basically I have a bunch of these form elements like the one above . If that element has a checkbox that is checked I want it the form element removed.

Comment: @JoelSmith so if the checkbox within the form is checked then you want to form to be removed is that it

Comment: Yes exactly and if you can write it to do that when the page loads that will fit the problem exactly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#incomplete').find('form input:checkbox:checked').closest("div").remove()
```

It uses implicit iteration over the set of elements returned by the find. The closest() method returns the closest ancestor element that matches the select ("div").

Comment: If you want to delete the form element then replace "div" with "form"